# Medpy AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'astype'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hello i am trying to calculate average surface distance (asd) using Medpy with latest libraries of keras and tensorflow. Any help in this regard is appreciated. Here is my code and error:

```
from medpy import metric as M

asd=M.binary.asd(tf.cast(y_pred, np.float32),tf.cast(y_true, np.float32),voxelspacing=None,connectivity=1)
```

Error:

> File "/home/rak038/Segmentation/U-net/noGPU/noGPU/lib/python3.7/site-packages/medpy/metric/binary.py", line 1200, in __surface_distances

```
result = numpy.atleast_1d(result.astype(numpy.bool))
```

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`astype` is a Numpy function. Here I guess `result` is a `tf.Tensor`, so you need to use `tf.cast` to change its type instead (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast).

Comment: I have used tf.cast to change its data type but still the problem remains the same

Comment: What is the type or `result` ?

Answer (score 3):

`tensor.numpy()` can change your type from tensor to `numpy`, it will have the attribute `astype`